# Convert string to Double C#

Tags: c#, sql, type-conversion

I have a field in DB which is float. My application is WindowsForm. I need to convert the value in textbox of the format 43.27 to double.
When I do this COnvert.ToDouble(txtbox.Text) I get exception saying input string is wrong format.
How to rectify this issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try specifying a culture when parsing:

```
// CultureInfo.InvariantCulture would use "." as decimal separator
// which might not be the case of the current culture
// you are using in your application. So this will parse
// values using "." as separator.
double d = double.Parse(txtbox.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And to handle the error case for gracefully instead of throwing exceptions around you could use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) method:

```
double d;
if (double.TryParse(txtbox.Text, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
    // TODO: use the parsed value
}
else
{
    // TODO: tell the user to enter a correct number
}
```

Comment: Is it not better to do it via TryParse instead of Parse?

Comment: @Amokrane, yeah, it's better.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to convert a string to number, you need to be sure which format does the string use. E.g. in English, there is a decimal point (“43.27”), while in Czech, there is a decimal comma (“43,27”).

By default, the current locale is used; if you *know* the number uses the English conversion, you need to specify the culture explicitly, e.g.

```
Convert.ToDouble(txtBox.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```