# Convert from textbox string to double in C#

Tags: c#

I'm doing a system on C# and everything is going ok, but I'm having some troubles when I want convert a textbox value to double, for example: when I enter 123.40 the result of convert this to Double is 12340. Here is my code:

```
Double.Parse(txtPay.Text)
```

And if I try with:

```
Convert.ToDouble(txtPay.Text)
```

the result is the same

Comment: What is your system locale? I suspect that's the problem...

Comment: The laguage is Spanish(Mexico), Can this configuration be a problem? I'm frustred it's only one problem to continue with my system

Comment: It's not a problem. Just see @dcastro answer below.

Comment: I'm wondering how many times this question will be asked

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455306/why-double-parse0-05-returns-5-0) ,  [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040557/double-parse-doesnt-work-with-some-country-apparently) , [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp) , [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426978/c-sharp-convert-string-to-double-in-locale), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056554/convert-string-to-double-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `.` is not the decimal separator in your locale - instead, it's probably `,`, which means you'd have to enter `123,40`.

However, you can use an invariant culture to parse a double where `.` is used as the decimal separator.

```
using System.Globalization;

Double.Parse("4.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also, it's highly recommended that you use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Parse` or `Convert` to validate user input and avoid exceptions.

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried it and everything it's ok!

Comment: @Pepe If that worked for you, please mark his answer as "the answer" so he gets the reputation. Thanks.